# Real-time face_recognition can't indentify the right face

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, face-recognition

I want to build an attendance system by face_recognition with real-time.  Therefore, I created a folder that have 20 pictures of some famous people to test the code. However, the result is bad, since the program can't really identify the right face.  What should I do to improve the code such that I can identify the right faces?

I hope to get some advice from you.  Thanks a lot.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#I have installed these package successfully
import face_recognition
import cv2
import datetime
import glob2 as gb
import numpy as np

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#There are 20 pictures in my local folder
img_path=gb.glob(r'F:\liuzhenya\photo\\*.jpg')
#Store the name of picture
known_face_names=[]
#Store the matrix from these pictures
known_face_encodings=[]
for i in img_path:
    picture_name=i.replace('F:\liuzhenya\photo\\','')
    picture_newname=picture_name.replace('.jpg','')
    obama_img = face_recognition.load_image_file(i)
    obama_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(obama_img)[0]
    known_face_names.append(picture_newname)
    known_face_encodings.append(obama_face_encoding)

face_locations = []
face_encodings = []
face_names = []
process_this_frame = True


while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
    rgb_small_frame=small_frame[:,:,::-1]
    if process_this_frame:
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)

        face_names = []
        for face_encoding in face_encodings:
            match = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
            if True in match:
                match_index=match.index(True)
                name = "match"
                #To print name and time
                cute_clock = datetime.datetime.now()
                print (known_face_names[match_index]+':'+str(cute_clock))
            else:
                name = "unknown"
            face_names.append(name)

    process_this_frame = not process_this_frame

    for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
        top *= 4
        right *= 4
        bottom *= 4
        left *= 4

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255),  2)

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left+6, bottom-6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)

    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: face1] [image: face2]

[image: face3]

[image: face4]

Comment: Below the code is my result and test folder.Thanks for your help.

Comment: face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings,face_encoding,tolerance=0.39)